# Merging parts of GOPRO clips with concat filter produces the ffmpeg buffer error

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Here is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -y  -ss 670497ms  -i "GX030058.MP4" -to 25977ms  -i "GX040058.MP4" \
 -filter_complex   \
"[0][1]concat=v=1:a=1 [concv] [conca]" \
 -map [concv] -map [conca] \
 "out.mp4"
```

it produces the following error and the audio goes out of sync

```
[out_0_0 @ 0x7fca2d508bc0] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.s speed=0.539x    
[out_0_1 @ 0x7fca2d5093c0] 100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
[out_0_1 @ 0x7fca2d5093c0] 1000 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
```

If I just issue command:

```
ffmpeg -y  -ss 670497ms  -i "GX030058.MP4" -to 25977ms  -i "GX040058.MP4" "out.mp4"
```

Then audio has no problems.

The reason I use the filter, because the actual filter is more complex and also includes adding the overlay to these concatenated clips, but the problem exists even with concat operation only.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem by having separate concat filters for audio and video:

```
ffmpeg -y  -ss 670497ms  -i GX030058.MP4 \
 -to 25977ms  -i GX040058.MP4 \
 -filter_complex   \
 "[0][1] concat=v=1:a=0 [concv]; [0][1] concat=v=0:a=1 [conca]" \
 -map [concv] -map [conca] \
 out.mp4
```